Conda environment in Nextflow config withLabel field doesn't work?
I'm trying to enforce using a specific conda environment in a withLabel context. Here is an example nextflow script:
process testConda {
    label 'test_process'

    script:
    """
    which conda
    conda env list
    echo "Current Conda env: \$CONDA_PREFIX"
    """
}

workflow {
    testConda()
}

It works when using a profile via nextflow run test.nf -profile test
profiles {
    test {
        conda.enabled = true
        process {
            conda = "/data/user/miniconda3/envs/test" 
        }
    }
}

However if I define a global process withLabel definition and run nextflow run test.nf it does not work:
process {
    conda.enabled = true
    withLabel: 'test_process' {
        conda = "/data/user/miniconda3/envs/test"
        beforeScript = "echo 'Using test_process'"
    }
}

When checking the .command.log the Using test_process is present so it is using the right config, but the stdout indicates it is using base env not test. Does the conda config not work in the withLabel context?

This configuration works me using nextflow version 23.04.3.5875:
profiles {
  conda {
    conda.enabled = true
}
}

process {
    withLabel: foo {
        conda = '/data/user/miniconda3/envs/test'
    }
}

nextflow run main.nf -profile conda

Trying to combine withLabel with conda.enabled when conda isn't enabled inside the profile scope does not work for me either.

Ya I've found it works when using a profile, what I'm trying to do is specify using a label and no profile - which works for everything except conda for some reason?
